# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH for NodeJS SocketIO server in a docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, ssl, socket.io, ssl-certificate

So i have a nodejs socketio server inside a docker container. The server uses the same url as the site, just on port 3001, and the same certificate and key. However, i get this error and i cant understand why at all, Ive tried everything from different ciphers and tls versions to deleting and starting over. Server is running as I can see in portainer and if i configure it as http and on client side call it as https, i get error, but i change the link to http and i can see the output. Tested locally with docker without ssl and worked. Certificate is available and works well for other parts of the site. i havent touched nginx config if that matters.

Below is my index.js:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require("https");
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const path = require('path');


const app = express();

const keyPath = path.join(__dirname, 'ssl', 'mykey.key');
const certPath = path.join(__dirname, 'ssl', 'mycert.crt');


const readKeyFile = () => {
  try {
    console.log(fs.readFileSync(keyPath))
    return fs.readFileSync(keyPath);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error reading SSL key file:', err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

const readCertFile = () => {
  try {
    console.log(fs.readFileSync(certPath))
    return fs.readFileSync(certPath);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error reading SSL certificate file:', err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

const transports = ["websocket", "polling"]; 

const options = {
  key: readKeyFile(),
  cert: readCertFile(),
  transports: transports
};



const httpsServer = https.createServer(app, options);

const io = new Server(httpsServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: ["https://my-site.com"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});


io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`User Connected: ${socket.id}`);

  socket.on("join_room", (data) => {
    socket.join(data);
  });

  socket.on("send_message", (data) => {
    socket.to(data.room).emit("receive_message", data);
  });
});

httpsServer.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("HTTP SERVER IS RUNNING");
});
```

this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.8.0

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3001
EXPOSE 3002  

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

any suggestions would be extremely appreciated

I tried adding different ciphers, tls versions, cors any origin, http server (resulted in mixed content error), transports, nothing worked unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this issue is causing because your ssl certificate isn't valid
you may need to buy a certificate, but my personally i use [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/)
for all my development projects

Comment: This error has nothing to do with certificate validation.

Comment: then the problem is from the nginx server, you didn't configure right